# Load Json Nested to Dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

stackoverflow, please help me.
i have json file.json like this.

```
{"info":[
    {"name":"LYDIANA","address":[{"home":"San Francisco"},{"work":"Carolina"}],"emails":[],"phones":[{"work":"1234567"},{"home":"4323455"}]},
    {"name":"John Doe","address":[{"home":"Laguna"},{"work":"Ivory"}],"emails":[{"email":"john@gmail.com"},{"email":"doe@gmail.com"}],"phones":[{"work":"5435435"},{"work":"8678678"}]}
]}
```

how to create dataframe pandas like this?

```
name        address                                 phones
LYDIANA     home: San Francisco | work: Carolina    1234567
LYDIANA     home: San Francisco | work: Carolina    4323455
John Doe    home: Laguna | work: Ivory              5435435
John Doe    home: Laguna | work: Ivory              8678678
```

Comment: What about emails?

Comment: it doesn't make much sense to merge home and work address into single string (and repeat it) while keeping phone on separate lines without any indication is it work or home phone

Comment: @IoaTzimas I don't want to use email in a dataframe

Comment: @buran it's possible, you can see the answer in this thread my friend

Comment: I did not say it's not possible, just that it does not make sense. You loose important information about phone and at the same time keep redundant duplicate information about address.

Comment: @buran Thank you for your advice, this data from my contact phone. between the address and phones fields are not related. phone number can be distinguished by a prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

dct = {"info":[
    {"name":"LYDIANA","address":[{"home":"San Francisco"},{"work":"Carolina"}],"emails":[],"phones":[{"work":"1234567"},{"home":"4323455"}]},
    {"name":"John Doe","address":[{"home":"Laguna"},{"work":"Ivory"}],"emails":[{"email":"john@gmail.com"},{"email":"doe@gmail.com"}],"phones":[{"work":"5435435"},{"work":"8678678"}]}
]}

all_data = []
for row in dct['info']:
    all_data.append({
            'name': row['name'],
            'address': ' | '.join('{}: {}'.format(k, v) for a in row['address'] for k, v in a.items()),
            'phones': [v for p in row['phones'] for v in p.values()]
        })

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data).explode('phones')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       name                               address   phones
0   LYDIANA  home: San Francisco | work: Carolina  1234567
0   LYDIANA  home: San Francisco | work: Carolina  4323455
1  John Doe            home: Laguna | work: Ivory  5435435
1  John Doe            home: Laguna | work: Ivory  8678678
```